# javascript in php and using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm getting really confused with php,ajax and javascript.
I'm using some ajax code  I got from w3 schools to handle a form and display it below the form input. However, I can't seem to get my php and Javascript right. I'm using JavaScript in php tags  where I then Get my variable in the same php tags and echo it. I then try to get that variable in ajax. I don't think I'm correctly getting the variable with ajax and inside my php. Does anyone have some advice.
Thanks

Heres my javascript in my html doc

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "hackacronymphp.php?phpAnswer=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

Here's the last part of my script with my php afterward all inside one php tag

```
    var stringe = vari.join("");
     console.log(stringe);
    var answer = dataarray[stringe];
    console.log(answer);
    </script>
    $phpanswer = $_GET['answer']
    echo $phpanswer ;
?>
```

Comment: The file 'hackacronymphp.php' should be looking up a database or retrieving the data from a file. The code you supplied it looks as though you already have the 'answer' within the JavaScript code (within an array), therefore php/ajax is not required.

Comment: I use a form action. Also hopefully in the future I will be using a database.I want to show the data under the submit button without going to another page. Any advice?

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically load something via ajax?  You should be retrieving everything in php and displaying it in the html on the first page load.  Ajax can then be used to retrieve additional data dynamically if need be (but if you don't need to, then don't bother with the unnecessary extra page requests).  Don't forget, php code will execute server side, while javascript code executes on the client side (i.e. in their browser).